# Is There a way of returning a queryset of the first instance of a specific field from a django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Say i have a model called Workout, and its populated as such[image]

I want to return a queryset of the first instance of each new date filterd by the current user. In this case, if the current logged in user is user_id = 1, the queryset would contain the workout objects with id 1,4 and 5. Is there a way of achieving this using a Workout.objects... method?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use distinct on the date field to get unique Workouts based on the date field.

```
Workout.objects.filter(user=user).distinct('date')
```